# Elastic search query for avg on basis of condition

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, dsl

I have written an elastic search query the payload looks like

**"userData": [ { "sub":1234, "value":678,"condition" :"A" },{ "sub":1234, "value":678,"condition" :"B" }]**

Query :

```
{ 
  "aggs": { 
    "student_data": { 
      "date_histogram": { 
        "field":"@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval":"minute"
      },
      "aggs": { 
        "user_avg": { 
          "avg": { 
            "field":"value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result gives the avg for both the values i.e. for condition A and for condition B also but what I actually want is the avg for just condition B on the basis of the time period for min interval.

Comment: Is this the only query you are executing?

Comment: @Kapil yes it is a part of query which I'm executing

Comment: Share your mappings please.

Comment: @Kapil: query would take all document where condition B is present, so A condition will be take in consideration into the aggregation , you have to add an agg_filter inside (please not i put a term inside the filter, we need the mapping to know if we must use a query_string, a term or something else. We also need the mapping to test, because i thinck we need to map this as a nested fields

Comment: {
"query":{
"query_string":{
"query":"condition:B"
}
},
"aggs":{
"student_data":{
"date_histogram":{
"field":"@timestamp",
"calendar_interval":"minute"
},
"aggs" : {
        "condition_B" : {
            "filter" : { "term": { "condition": "b" } },
            "aggs" : {
                "user_avg" : { "avg" : { "field" : "value" } }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
}

Comment: @LeBigCat Yes just realized it.

Comment: @LeBigCat conditions A and B are dynamic values they can be anything. As well as there can be n numbers of conditions but every timestamp will contain all the conditions

Comment: Plus I need average of every single condition

Comment: Is **userData** of nested type field or object?

Comment: @LeBigCat The above query works perfectly fine with the static conditions. it can be done with dynamic values. There can be any no of values as well as each condition is different. So if there are 5 conditions I need to get an average of 5 different values on the basis of condition

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant its of Object type

Comment: @Harmeet Kaur I saw your comment after posting. consider changing to a nested type, it is more common when using array of object.

Comment: @LeBigCat "query_string":{ "query":"condition:B" }  what  is "condition:B" here in the query provided by you in above comments

Comment: @LeBigCat And what if I needed the array of which avg is being calculated, How can I get that

Answer (score 2):

Base on your payload I assume `userData` is a `nested` type.

This is a working example of how to average every single condition (nested inner):

**Mapping**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "userData": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "condition": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "sub": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index few documents**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "@timestamp": "2019-11-08T11:15:24.188Z",
  "userData": [
    {
      "sub": 1234,
      "value": 678,
      "condition": "A"
    },
    {
      "sub": 1234,
      "value": 620,
      "condition": "B"
    }
  ]
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "@timestamp": "2019-11-08T11:15:44.188Z",
  "userData": [
    {
      "sub": 1234,
      "value": 680,
      "condition": "A"
    },
    {
      "sub": 1234,
      "value": 640,
      "condition": "B"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search query**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "student_data": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "minute"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "data": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "userData"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "condition": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "userData.condition.keyword"
              }, 
              "aggs": {
                "user_avg": {
                  "avg": {
                    "field": "userData.value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"student_data" : {
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key_as_string" : "2019-11-08T11:15:00.000Z",
      "key" : 1573211700000,
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "data" : {
        "doc_count" : 4,
        "condition" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "A",
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "user_avg" : {
                "value" : 679.0
              }
            },
            {
              "key" : "B",
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "user_avg" : {
                "value" : 630.0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Assael Azran Thank you. The query works. Can you help me in getting all the elements also which are giving the avg value in an array